# Angularjs pass $scope method as parameter to another $scope method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

How do you pass one scope method as a required parameter into another scope method?

In this case, I need to be able to pass `$scope.getPublisher(publisher)` as the second parameter in `$scope.modal`.

There's a lot of code, so here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/psdpainter/spmPB/

Comment: Use prototypical inheritance (if they're nested), event emitters with `$on` if they're very simple in their communication and a service otherwise.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Can't you just call getPublisher inside the modal function?   $scope.modal = function (title, publisherId, publishdate, body, expiration) {
       var publisher = $scope.getPublisher(publisherId);
      return headlineFactory.modalDialog(title, publisher, publishdate, body, expiration);
    };

Comment: That's one of the first things I thought, but it returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was `$scope.getPublisher` was resolving before `$scope.modal` knew what it was. This is the correct code:

```
$scope.modal = function (title, id, publishdate, body, expiration) {
    var id = id.Publisher1Id;
    headlineFactory.getUserDetails(id).then(function (data) {
        var user = data.d;
        return user;
    })
    .then(function (user) {
        var id = user.Title;
            headlineFactory.modalDialog(title, id, publishdate, body, expiration);
    });
};
```